# Update a single column to EF 6.0 using LINQ lambda ? MVC4

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to save the data when i edit something in my data-table on enter .
On enter control goes to method in controller where actual update performs .

My code till this point:

```
public string UpdateData(int id, string value, int? rowId, int? columnPosition, int? columnId, string columnName)
{
     var Leadsinfo = ser_obj1.Lead_List();

     if (columnPosition == 0 && Leadsinfo.Any(c => c.Contact_Name.ToLower().Equals(value.ToLower())))
         return "Lead with a name '" + value + "' already exists";
     var Lead = Leadsinfo.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Lead_Id == id);
     if (Lead == null)
     {
         return "Lead with an id = " + id + " does not exists";
     }
     switch (columnPosition)
     {
         case 0:
             Lead.Contact_Name = value;
             iWise_NeoEntities ooo = new iWise_NeoEntities();
             break;
         case 1:
             Lead.Contact_Address = value;
             break;
         case 2:
             Lead.Lead_Source = value;
             break;
         case 3:
             Lead.Domain = value;
             break;
         default:
             break;
     }
     return value;
}
```

In the above code i mentioned i need to write logic where it should save to DB upon any column editing . using lambda linq is easy i guess , But i dont know even how to start ?
Do i need to write save under each case?

Comment: you will need to use your context's 'SaveChanges' method. you will not need to put it in every case. I would put it under the switch statement. ef will detect what data has been changed on save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create update method in database:

```
public void UpdateLead(Lead model)
{
    var entity = db.Set<Lead>().Find(model.Id);
    db.Entry<Lead>(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And use it where you need:

```
switch (columnPosition)
{
     case 0:       Lead.Contact_Name = value;      break;
     case 1:       Lead.Contact_Address = value;   break;
     case 2:       Lead.Lead_Source = value;       break;
     case 3:       Lead.Domain = value;            break;
     default:                                      break;
}

iWise_NeoEntities ooo = new iWise_NeoEntities();

ooo.UpdateLead(Lead);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much . That's the beauty of the code